# How to make outer div with border-radius to cut off inner div

Tags: css, mobile-webkit, iscroll

This is the demo(works only in webkit browsers) [Demo](http://jsbin.com/erumid/1/edit)
I have an outer div, which have rounded corners on all four edges. I have a ul list inside it . The list is made to scroll with iscroll. The problem is the list's li items without border-radius is affecting the outer divs, rounded corner.
Please see the demo. See the bottom, there will no rounded corner. And once you scroll down , the top will not not have rounded corner.

Answer (score 1):

The `border-radius` should be on `#viewport`, but still won't work due to an unsolved bug in Webkit that lets child content appear over the parent's rounded corners: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71639

Comment: Does this same bug exists in iphones and anroid mobiles

Comment: It is a bug in the core Webkit framework, so it very likely applies to all Webkit-based browsers, be they desktop or mobile. You might work around it by using images for the corners; [here's some tutorial found off Google](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/reusable-transparent-css-rounded-corners/).